# PHP Condicionales ternarios

Tags: php, operador-ternario

Me preguntaba si existía alguna forma de realizar un codicional ternario que solo evalue una condición verdadera y no una falsa.

Por ejemplo, el condicional ternario en php sería:

```
$n = (2) ? true : false;
```

Mi idea sería realizar un condicional ternario tal que:

```
$n = (2) ? true;
```

he probado de diferentes maneras pero todas me dan error, así que supongo que no existe manera, pero por si acaso lo pregunto por aquí.

Gracias! :)

Os pongo el código entero sin el ejemplo anterior:

```
function encrypt($chr) {

  if($chr === 'Ñ') { return 0; }

  $abc = array(    'A' => 2,    'B' => 22,
                   'C' => 222,  'D' => 3,
                   'E' => 33,   'F' => 333,
                   'G' => 4,    'H' => 44,
                   'I' => 444,  'J' => 5,
                   'K' => 55,   'L' => 555,
                   'M' => 6,    'N' => 66,
                   'O' => 666,  'P' => 7,
                   'Q' => 77,   'R' => 777,
                   'S' => 7777, 'T' => 8,
                   'U' => 88,   'V' => 888,
                   'W' => 9,    'X' => 99,
                   'Y' => 999,  'Z' => 9999 );

      return $abc[$chr];
}
```

Mi idea simplemente era usar un ternario en lugar de un if, (por estética) sé que es una tonteria. De ahí que me preguntase si se pudiese hacer algo como:

```
return $chr == 'Ñ' ? true : false;
```

La cosa es que solo quiero retornar el true, no el false, si es false mi idea es que siga con el código.

Comment: Y por qué no quieres evaluar el false ?

Comment: No me termina de quedar clara la pregunta. ¿Quieres un condicional ternario que no tenga una parte para cuando la condición no se cumple?

Comment: Sé que se puede hacer lo contrario (con el operador elvis `?:`) que es básicamente asignar el valor para el true y sólo dar valor para el `false`.

Comment: Además de lo comentado, en tu ejemplo estas asignando el valor a n con "=", debería ser comparación "==" para que el condicional tenga sentido.

Comment: cual sería el contexto? `$x = ($n == 2) ? true : $x;` que error da?

Comment: @Carmen es una asignación condicional. En ese caso lo que se hace es que se evalúa `2` (que es verdadero) y se irá por la rama del verdadero, por lo que `$n` tendrá el valor `true`. Lo que se está haciendo es `$n = (2 ? true : false)` porque [el operador ternario tiene precedencia sobre la asignación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro claro, siempre va a ser verdadero, no es necesario evaluar que sea verdadero en este contexto, aunque se puede evaluar

Comment: y que retorna si la condición es `false` ?

Comment: @aloMalbarez El contexto en este caso es comprobar si el caracter es Ñ en caso de serlo la funcion retorna el valor 0, de no serlo sigues dentro de la función (haciendo otras cosas). El problema es que no quiero usar un if. Podría usar if($chr === 'Ñ') { return 0; } pero se me antojo el querer usar el ternario. (Es una tonteria, lo sé, de ahi que me preguntase si era posible) ya que de no ser verdadero, mi idea es que siga con el código (else) pero no puedo obviamente meter todo el resto del código dentro de la evaluacion ternaria.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se podría hacer de otra manera con un operador ternario: mueve la definición de `$abc` al principio de la función y luego pon `return $chr === 'Ñ' ? 0 : $abc[$chr];` como última operación.

Comment: dará error de sintaxis, el ternario usa "expresiones" y `return` es una "sentencia" del tipo "construccion de lenguaje" (no es una función)

Comment: si ese es todo el código `$abc['Ñ']=0;` retornará `0`

Answer (score 1):

Por la propia naturaleza de del operador ternario no puedes hacer un operador ternario que solo devuelva true en caso de que la expresión a evaluar sea verdadera y nada en caso de que sea falsa.

> A partir de PHP 5.3, es posible dejar de lado la parte media del
>   operador ternario. La expresión **expr1 ?: expr3** retorna **expr1** si **expr1**
>   se evalúa como **TRUE** y **expr3** si es de otra manera.

Por consiguiente lo único que se podría hacer:

```
$n = 2;
/* Si la expresion a evaluar es verdadera devuelve true 
pero si no , devolverá false (o lo que le indiques)*/
$resultado = ($n === 2) ?: false;  
$resultado; // true

$resultado = ($n === 5) ?: false;  
$resultado; // false
```

Que es lo mismo que :

```
$n = 2;
$resultado = ($n === 2) ? true : false;
$resultado; // true

$resultado = ($n === 5) ? true : false;
$resultado; // false
```

Aqui en la documentación oficial de PHP hay un apartado que hablan sobre el operador ternario: [Operadores de comparación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

La misma palabra lo dice, ternario. La operación debe estar compuesta por 3 partes, la evaluación, y los dos tipos de retorno. Por sintaxis `$n = 2 ? true;` está mal hecho y te retornará errores, es por eso que su estructura no debe ser violada siguiendo el patrón:

> Evaluación ? Si evaluación es verdadera : Si evaluación es falsa;

```
//Comparación booleana
$check = false;
$isChecked = $check ? true : false;

//Comparación numérica
$num = 5;
$isGrater = $num > 5 : true : false;

//Dos o más validaciones
$num = 5; 
$isChecked = true;
$checkedAndGreater = $num > 5 && $isChecked ? true : false;

//Anidación ternaria
$getId = false;
$age = 18;    
$barAccess = $getId ? 'Bienvenido' : $age === 18 ? 'Bienvenido, cerveza?' : 'No puedes pasar';

//Recuerda que en boolean cualquier número diferente de 0 es TRUE, por lo que si evalúas el 2, será siempre TRUE, la forma correcta sería
$n = 2;
$n = $n === 2 ? 'Es dos' : 'No es dos;
```

Todos los casos deben tener 3 partes, si no dejaría de ser evaluación ternaria, no puedes romper esa sintaxis.

Saludos

Comment: A partir de PHP 5.3, es posible dejar de lado la parte media del operador ternario. La expresión expr1 ?: expr3 retorna expr1 si expr1 se evalúa como TRUE y expr3 si es de otra manera