# Uso de operador ternario o condicionales en PHP

Tags: php, php7

¿Cómo se debería asignar un valor a una variable en base a una condición, mediante bloques if/else o usando operadores ternarios?

```
if ($x) {
    $result = $x;
} else {
    $result = $y;
}
```

o bien

```
$result = $x ? $x : $y;
```

Quisiera saber ¿en qué situaciones puede usarse una u otra? y si ¿la elección afecta solo a la legibilidad?

Answer (score 1):

El uso de estructuras if/else o del operador ternario, para dar valor a una variable, son dos opciones válidas que van a afectar sobretodo a la legibilidad del código, si bien la primera opción es más interesante para *comprobar* los valores asignados y la opción válida para realizar múltiples asignaciones.

```
<?php
// Imaginemos que tenemos dos variables $x y $y. Les asignó valores para hacer
// algunas pruebas con condicionales, en las que le asignare el valor de una
// de las variables anteriores a una tercera que imprimire para ver su valor
$x = 5;
$y = 7;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Método 1: uso de estructura condicional
if ($x) { // $x es mayor que 0, por lo que se evalua como true
    $result = $x;
} else {
    $result = $y;
}
echo $result . PHP_EOL;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Método 2: Asignación de un valor mediante un operador ternario
$result = null; // reset
$result = $x ? $x : $y;
echo $result . PHP_EOL;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Método 3: Asignación de un valor mediante un operador ternario simplificado
$result = null; // reset
$result = $x ?: $y;
echo $result . PHP_EOL;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Consideraciones y recomendaciones

// Variación del método 1: eliminar el bloque else usando un valor por defecto
$result = null; // reset
$result = $y;
if ($x) {
    $result = $x;
}
echo $result . PHP_EOL;
// esto debería hacerse siempre con asignaciones directas de valores literales: 
// un número, un string, etc. Cuando se asignan valores a partir acciones como 
// operaciones dentro de métodos, llamadas a la BD, etc. tiene más sentido 
// emplear la estructura "if / else" clásica por una cuestión de rendimiento
// y porque será más facil hacer debug en caso de fallos


// Escribir las ternarias en varias líneas
// La expresion:
$result = $x ? $x : $y;

// puede indicarse en 2:
$result = $x 
    ? $x : $y;

// o más líneas:
$result = $x 
    ? $x 
    : $y;
// Yo suelo usar la de 2 líneas, o 3 si su contenido es largo.
// Si se usa Git debería evitarse superar el límite de 72 caracteres desde el
// inicio de la línea, de igual forma como el "diff" se basa en líneas se 
// recomienda escribir el código seraparando las expresiones y asignaciones en 
// diferentes líneas


// Escribir la condición de las ternarias entre paréntesis
// Por claridad, al usar un ternario la condición debería ir entre paréntesis
$result = null; // reset
$result = ($x) ? $x : $y;
echo $result . PHP_EOL;

// esto es especialmente recomendable cuando hay expresiones de comparación
// así, el siguiente código 
$result = null; // reset
$result = ! $result && $x 
    ? $x : $y;
echo $result . PHP_EOL;
//debería escribirse como
$result = null; // reset
$result = (! $result && $x) 
    ? $x : $y;
echo $result . PHP_EOL;
```

> Fuentes consultadas:

[PHP Condicionales ternarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178910/php-condicionales-ternarios/178921#178921)

https://blog.aulaformativa.com/haciendo-uso-del-operador-ternario-en-php/