# Duda Operador PHP

Tags: php, operador

Hola alguien podría decirme que significa el siguiente operador en php
?:

Se que el operador ?, se usa para cuando una u otra variable es verdadera pero no se que signifique en combinación con los dobles puntos.

Comment: Se llama operador ternario, es una forma abreviada de `if` por ejemplo, en la expresión `$y = $x < 10 ? 'Es menor' : 'Es Mayor o Igual';` si $x tiene un valor menor que 10 entonces en $y se almacena la cadena 'Es menor', de lo contrario se almacena 'Es mayor o Igual'.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas la forma de hacer preguntas que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Ejemplos de uso de los operadores ternarios en sus diferentes formas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243215/20709

Answer (score 0):

El operador `?` nos sirve para generar un if abreviado 
Ejemplo:

```
$status = (true) ? true:false;
```

Sería lo mismo que ejecutar

```
if(true){
 $status = true;
}else{
 $status = false
}
```

Es ahí donde nos sirve el operador `?` para generar un código mas limpio y legible.

Answer (score 0):

a lo que preguntas se le llama "OPERADOR TERNARIO" puedes buscarlo en Google si gustas, pero básicamente lo que hace es lo sig:

*sentencia booleana ? valor si la sentencia es cierta : valor si es falsa*

un Ejemplo:

**Sentencia común:**

```
if ($A == $B) {
  $res = "La variable A es igual a la B";
} else {
  $res = "La variable A es distinta a la B";
}
```

**Con operador Ternario:**

```
$res = ($A == $B) ? "A es igual a B" : "A no es igual a B";
```

Listo, cualquier otra duda, ya sabes como buscarlo en Google, saludos.